# Parquet vs ORC vs ORC with Snappy

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet, snappy, orc

I am running a few tests on the storage formats available with Hive and using Parquet and ORC as major options. I included ORC once with default compression and once with Snappy.

I have read many a documents that state Parquet to be better in time/space complexity as compared to ORC but my tests are opposite to the documents I went through.

Follows some details of my data.

```
Table A- Text File Format- 2.5GB

Table B - ORC - 652MB

Table C - ORC with Snappy - 802MB

Table D - Parquet - 1.9 GB
```

Parquet was worst as far as compression for my table is concerned.

My tests with the above tables yielded following results.

**Row count operation**

```
Text Format Cumulative CPU - 123.33 sec

Parquet Format Cumulative CPU - 204.92 sec

ORC Format Cumulative CPU - 119.99 sec 

ORC with SNAPPY Cumulative CPU - 107.05 sec
```

**Sum of a column operation**

```
Text Format Cumulative CPU - 127.85 sec   

Parquet Format Cumulative CPU - 255.2 sec   

ORC Format Cumulative CPU - 120.48 sec   

ORC with SNAPPY Cumulative CPU - 98.27 sec
```

**Average of a column operation**

```
Text Format Cumulative CPU - 128.79 sec

Parquet Format Cumulative CPU - 211.73 sec    

ORC Format Cumulative CPU - 165.5 sec   

ORC with SNAPPY Cumulative CPU - 135.45 sec
```

**Selecting 4 columns from a given range using where clause**

```
Text Format Cumulative CPU -  72.48 sec 

Parquet Format Cumulative CPU - 136.4 sec       

ORC Format Cumulative CPU - 96.63 sec 

ORC with SNAPPY Cumulative CPU - 82.05 sec
```

Does that mean ORC is faster then Parquet? Or there is something that I can do to make it work better with query response time and compression ratio?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share a generic algorithm used to do that experiment? It is necessary to use the same data, though. But sharing everything else to accomplish the same results with different datasets might be very useful to give you a better answer or to prove that you have a very good point and to change the world forever.

Comment: do you have any spark vs tez results using orc vs parquet? from what I have saw it seems like tez is faster (3 times faster) when using orc format.

Comment: + 1 for your nice benchmarking overview. Anyhow, is there a chance you can provide an updated version since some technical aspects behind the scenes have changed (for example like discussed in @jonathanChap 's answer)?

Answer (score 54):

I would say, that both of these formats have their own advantages.

Parquet might be better if you have highly nested data, because it stores its elements as a tree like **Google Dremel** does ([See here](https://blog.twitter.com/2013/dremel-made-simple-with-parquet)).
Apache ORC might be better if your file-structure is flattened.

And as far as I know parquet does not support Indexes yet. ORC comes with a light weight Index and since Hive 0.14 an additional Bloom Filter which might be helpful the better query response time especially when it comes to sum operations.

The Parquet default compression is SNAPPY. Are Table A - B - C and D holding the same Dataset? If yes it looks like there is something shady about it, when it only compresses to 1.9 GB

Comment: Table A - Text File Format - No Compression......... Table B - ORC file format with ZLIB compression......... Table C - ORC with Snappy....... Table D - Parquet with Snappy.....    I worked on another table with ~150 columns and ~160 GB in size to check how the file formats perform there. Parquet took 35 GB to store that 160GB data while ORC with snappy took 39GB...... The compression looked way better for Parquet as compared to the test posted in question but performance was again on similar lines.. ORC shined here with even better performance than ORC+SNAPPY combination.

Comment: The data structure for my use cases was flatter without any nesting. I agree to your indexing comment on Parquet vs ORC and that does make a difference actually. Do you have any results to share from the performance comparison of both? That might help to calm my conscience that I am implementing the formats correctly. :)

Comment: I never tested my dataset on Parquet because the Index was a necessary requirement and we also have a flat data structure with no nested information.
What i figured out is, that depending on where you store your files, you need a different stripe and file size to get best results. When you store your files permanently on HDFS it is better to have larger files and stripes. 
"set mapred.max.split.size=4096000000" was the parameter i used to influence the file size and a left the stripe size to its default value. With this setting it gave me about 94% query and compression boost.

Comment: If you want to store your files on Amazon S3 as a cold storage a way smaller file and stripe size gave me much better results. 
i used files of the size of 40-60MB containing a single Stripe.

Answer (score 52):

You are seeing this because:

- Hive has a vectorized ORC reader but no vectorized parquet reader.
- Spark has a vectorized parquet reader and no vectorized ORC reader.
- Spark performs best with parquet, hive performs best with ORC.

I've seen similar differences when running ORC and Parquet with Spark.

Vectorization means that rows are decoded in batches, dramatically improving memory locality and cache utilization.

(correct as of Hive 2.0 and Spark 2.1)

Comment: As of 2.3.0, spark _does_ have a vectorized ORC reader: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16060

Comment: Hive 2.3.0 has vectorized Parquet reader - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14815

Comment: Since Spark 2.3, Spark supports a vectorized ORC reader https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-orc.html

Answer (score 14):

Both Parquet and ORC have their own advantages and disadvantages. But I simply try to follow a simple rule of thumb - **"How nested is your Data and how many columns are there"**. If you follow the **Google Dremel** you can find how parquet is designed. They user a hierarchal tree-like structure to store data. More the nesting deeper the tree.

But **ORC** is designed for a flattened file store. So if your Data is flattened with fewer columns, you can go with ORC, otherwise, parquet would be fine for you. Compression on flattened Data works amazingly in ORC.

We did some benchmarking with a larger flattened file, converted it to spark Dataframe and stored it in both parquet and ORC format in **S3** and did querying with **Redshift-Spectrum **.

```
Size of the file in parquet: ~7.5 GB and took 7 minutes to write
Size of the file in ORC: ~7.1. GB and took 6 minutes to write
Query seems faster in ORC files.
```

Soon we will do some benchmarking for nested Data and update the results here.

Answer (score 8):

We did some benchmark comparing the different file formats (Avro, JSON, ORC, and Parquet) in different use cases.

https://www.slideshare.net/oom65/file-format-benchmarks-avro-json-orc-parquet

The data is all publicly available and benchmark code is all open source at:

https://github.com/apache/orc/tree/branch-1.4/java/bench

Comment: This is really useful, but there should be a disclaimer that @Owen works for Horton Works, which originally developed the ORC file format

Comment: Thanks! But the second link is broken. Can you please fix or remove it from your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Both of them have their advantages. We use Parquet at work together with Hive and Impala, but just wanted to point a few advantages of ORC over Parquet: during long-executing queries, when Hive queries ORC tables **GC is called about 10 times less frequently**. Might be nothing for many projects, but might be crucial for others.

ORC also takes much less time, when you need to select just a few columns from the table. Some other queries, especially with joins, also take less time because of vectorized query execution, which is not available for Parquet

Also, ORC compression is sometimes a bit random, while Parquet compression is much more consistent. It looks like when ORC table has many number columns - it doesn't compress as well. It affects both zlib and snappy compression

Answer (score 1):

The default file format for Spark is parquet, but for Hive is orc.
As far as I know (maybe I'm wrong), the ratio of compression using zlib is higher than with snappy but it requires more CPU. Snappy on the other hand is a great "decent" compression format when you don't want too much CPU consumption.

I haven't tried the parquet API to write/read files, but I have some experience doing that with ORC. The ORC format is great, but it has what it seems as a bottleneck when you're trying to write files at the same time in different threads of the same JVM process. And it also has some memory problems too. I had to make some minor changes in the classes

org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.MemoryManager
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl

in order to make it work better and faster (HDP 2.6.4.0).

As previous fellows have said, it all depends on your data structure, the API or framework you're using to read the data and what you're trying to do with that data.

ORC files have statistics at different levels (file, stripes and rows) that can improve a lot the performance when you're filtering data, for example.

ORC has also some improvements when writing if your columns have null values or the same value repeats often.

A benchmark is not that useful when what you're really trying to do has nothing to do with what the benchmark is testing.